# Qt acess ui of different class

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to access the ui elements of different class but getting error message. I've tried to do this for many hours but still failing, I feel that I am missing something simple.

I am trying to access an element "label" which is in `form.h`

mainwindow:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Form * elemForm = new Form(this);
    elemForm->ui; // works
    //elemForm->ui->label; // does not work
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Form();
    Ui::Form *ui;
private:

};

#endif // FORM_H
```

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label; //works fine here
}
```

Problem is in `mainwindow` file. I know this is inappropriate code, I'm just interested what I'm doing wrong. I am struggling to find whats wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Why would you even want to do such a thing? Create functions in your `Form` class that will allow you to do what you want with the label. `ui` should be a private member of a class.

Comment: @thuga Qt beginners are prone to think that way. I myself use that tricks too sometimes when I was new to Qt, though I create a function returning the `ui` pointer to keep it a private member.

Comment: @Tay2510 I wouldn't even recommend creating a function that returns the `ui` pointer. The whole point of the class becomes obsolete then. All `ui` manipulating should happen from within the class. Anything manipulating the `ui` stuff from outside the class would be poor design.

Comment: Please, consider another way of doing things. Take a look at another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `form.h`, you should also include `ui_form.h` in your `MainWindow.h`.

That's because the form elements are all defined in `Ui::Form` which is accessible by including :

```
#include "ui_form.h"
```

Comment: That's right. Nejat was faster :-). @OP: Please, don't do that in real code. That's horrible design.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to think on what are you doing, and how to do things better.

Don't feel think that method explained by Nejat is controversial to OOP? If you are trying to use OOP, learn how to do it and use it.

To get deeper understanding on what am I talking about, please, read this [short story about encapsulation](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/3).

---

Back to your example. Here is clean, simple and easy way to do what you want:

Your `mainwindow.h`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

// Include only header of your Form, not ui_form.h!
#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Form* elemForm = new Form(this);

    // Use public method of your Form object!
    elemForm->changeUI();
}
```

Your `form.h`:

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form();

    void changeUI(); // here you can do all what you want with your UI
private:
    Ui::Form *ui;
};
```

in `form.cpp` you'll have realization:

```
void Form::changeUI()
{
    ui->... // do all what you want with UI
}
```